# how to convert unixtime stamp in date format in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to convert the column unixtime data in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format but not getting it. The data type is numeric for my column.

I tried the following query but getting error:

```
select to_timestamp(starttime,'YYYY-MM-DD') , count(*) from cdrs_052019 group by 1
```

> Query execution failed
>
> Reason: SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_timestamp(numeric,
>   unknown) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and
>   argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position:
>   8

```
|starttime |endtime   |duration|duration_min|
|----------|----------|--------|------------|
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694960 |0       |            |
|155694960 |155694959 |1       |            |
```

Need results in following format:

```
starttime | count(*)

2019-05-01    56666
2019-05-02    77777
2019-05-03    69495
2019-05-04    4447
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,you can transform the timestamp to a date type by `::date`, As below is the example:

```
postgres=# select to_timestamp(1503504000);
      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2017-08-24 00:00:00+08
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_timestamp(1503504000)::date;
 to_timestamp 
--------------
 2017-08-24
(1 row)
```

The final SQL you want:

```
select 
    to_timestamp(starttime)::date as the_date, 
    count(1) 
from 
    cdrs_052019 
group by 
    to_timestamp(starttime)::date 
order by 
    the_date
```